# typescript express req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, postman

I can't find a way to get the json with typescript in the req.body instead of undefined or empty object.

```
const signupUser = ({ body }: Request, res: Response): void => {
  try {
    res.send(body)
    console.log(body)
  } catch (e) {
    handleHttp(res, 'ERROR_POST_ITEM')
  }
}
```

```
router.post('/signup', signupUser)
```

use middleware to return the json to me

```
app.use(express.json())
```

im testing with postman / RapidAPI Json/urlencoded

Comment: can you post the return of your request ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, the problem is that it is also necessary to add:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

I hope this can help someone, thank you